# Angular Provider config with data from ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I create a Provider to wrap pusher javascript in angular. I want to configure my pusher key from my play 2 server. Right now, I pass the key using ng-init. But how could I assign this key to the provider below. The reason I want to pass pusher key from the server is to use different key for development and product server.

page.scala.html

```
  <div data-ng-cloak>
    <div data-ng-view data-ng-init="pusherKey=@App.pusherAppKey()"></div>
  </div>
```

Configure the pusherProvider

```
  mod.config(["pusherProvider", function(pusherProvider) {
    pusherProvider.set('token', 'how do I use pusherKey here');
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using server-side templating anyway, you could try setting the key to a global variable:

```
<script>
    var pusherKey = "@App.pusherAppKey()";
</script>
```

And use it from JS:

```
mod.config(["pusherProvider", function(pusherProvider) {
    pusherProvider.set('token', pusherKey); // pusherKey here is the global
}]);
```

I find that keeping a *small* set of globals this way does not really harm. (I also keep user info this way.)